# HMAC Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, callback

I have been programming a middleware for my small application that verifies if an authentication header is present and verifies the HMAC present in it. I would like to know what I could optimize in this set of code. Any tips are appreciated.

```
const validator = require('validator'),
      crypto = require('crypto'),
      data = require('../database.js'),
      error = require('../utils/error.js')

const auth = function() {
  return function(req, res, next) {

    if(!req.authenticationHeaderExists) {
      res.json(error.INVALID_AUTH_HEADER)
      return
    }

    const authHeader = req.get('authentication').split(':')

    const user = authHeader[0]
    const userProvidedDigest = authHeader[1]

    if(!validator.isAlphanumeric(user)) {
      res.json(error.INVALID_USER)
      return
    }

    data.findOne({ user: user }, function processResults(err, docs) {
      if(err) {
        req.log.error(err)

        res.json(error.AN_ERROR_OCCURRED)
        return
      }

      if(docs == null) {
        res.json(error.USER_NOT_FOUND)
        return
      }

      const date = new Date()
      const formattedDate = date.getUTCFullYear().toString() + date.getUTCMonth().toString() + date.getUTCDate().toString() + date.getUTCHours().toString() + date.getUTCMinutes().toString()

      const serverGeneratedDigest = crypto.createHmac('sha256', docs.secretkey).update(formattedDate + req.method + req.url).digest('hex').toString('utf8')

      if(userProvidedDigest != serverGeneratedDigest) {
        res.json(error.INVALID_DIGEST)
        return
      }

      next()
    })
  }
}

module.exports = auth
```

Comment: Struggling to see how you could improve on this as the code looks pretty minimal. The obvious suggestion would be to introduce a layer of caching to reduce the no. of DB trips as I presume that would most likely be the biggest bottleneck.

Comment: Alright thank you for the suggestion @James, I wont be doing too much database queries, so I don´t think caching would be necessary. Either ways, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: doesn't this middleware run on every request?

Comment: Oh actually you're right, I'm using NeDB for the database, to store the username and secret key. What would be the best way to do the caching?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NeDB however by looking at the docs it would appear to be already suitable for fast access being an embedded / in-memory DB! Think at this point I'd be questioning are you trying to micro-optimise or do you actually have a real problem?

Comment: I was just trying to micro-optimize, just to check if there was anything I could improve.

Comment: try to get out the habit of micro-optimizing, improving where there is a problem or you know can be better is fine but improving code to the nth degree is wasted effort. In this case, unless you have a problem I would leave your code as-is, taking this code at face value I see no real improvements that could be made. I mean, personally I would rewrite with `async`  / `await` however that wouldn't add any value in terms of performance, just readability - which is still a good enough reason :)

Answer (score -2):

- You could optimize the `authHeader` variables to check if it exists using lexical and then do the split.
- You need to check if the `authHeader` splitted length is === 2.
- You didn't have to create a `const` of `function` returning `function` and then export it. Instead, you could just export the inside function as the default export.
- Use `return next();` for the last callback function or the process will still continued even if you already called `next();`

```
  const validator = require('validator'),
  crypto = require('crypto'),
  data = require('../database.js'),
  error = require('../utils/error.js')


module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  let authHeader = req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(':')
  if(!authHeader || authHeader.length !== 2) {
    return res.json(error.INVALID_AUTH_HEADER)
  }

  const user = authHeader[0]
  const userProvidedDigest = authHeader[1]

  if(!validator.isAlphanumeric(user)) {
    return res.json(error.INVALID_USER)
  }

  data.findOne({ user: user }, function processResults(err, docs) {
    if(err) {
      req.log.error(err)

      return res.json(error.AN_ERROR_OCCURRED)
    }

    if(docs === null) {
      return res.json(error.USER_NOT_FOUND)
    }

    const date = new Date()
    const formattedDate = date.getUTCFullYear().toString() + date.getUTCMonth().toString() + date.getUTCDate().toString() + date.getUTCHours().toString() + date.getUTCMinutes().toString()

    const serverGeneratedDigest = crypto.createHmac('sha256', docs.secretkey).update(formattedDate + req.method + req.url).digest('hex').toString('utf8')

    if(userProvidedDigest !== serverGeneratedDigest) {
      return res.json(error.INVALID_DIGEST)
    }

    return next()
  })
}
```

Comment: The question is how can performance be improved, not one of those suggestions address that problem.

Comment: I provide the answer how to improve the performance, what do you think this is for?

Comment: @Ihan read my previous comment - none of these suggestions will make one iota of difference to performance.

Comment: @James The question does not explicitly say "optimise *performance*". Also see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1884/31562 . Generally, answers are allowed to provide feedback to any aspects of the code.

Comment: @SimonForsberg based on the discussions via the comments it was my interpretation that's what the OP meant. Regardless, the improvements suggested here, IMO, won't make any sort of significant "optimisation" to the code therefore it would be making changes for the sake of it.

Comment: @james well that's only your interpretation, even a small bugs could cause bigger performance issue.